# SELECT bit-value in db worked on NAS, not on server

Tags: php, mysql, class, object, bit

I have some comboboxes with yes/no (value 1/0) that I store as a bit in my db. To put that value in the correct member of my object I do this:

```
class Member {
    var $active;

    public function refreshData() {
        $mysqli = connectdbMySQLI();

        $query = "SELECT * FROM tblMember WHERE ID = " . $this->id;
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $this->setData($row);
        $mysqli->close();
    }

    public function setData($row) {
        $this->active = $row['active'];
    }
}
```

Alle varchars, int and text-values or being assigned, except these bit values.
I checked with var_dump and I get an empty string

```
["active"]=> string(1) ""
```

Saving doesn't work as well:

```
$member = new Member(isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : null );
if(isset($_POST['active'])) {
    $member->active = $_POST['active'];
$member->save();
}
```

This I use to select the right value in the combobox:

```
<select type="text" name="active" id="active" class="txt">
    <option value="0" <?php echo $member->active == 0 ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>No</option>
    <option value="1" <?php echo $member->active == 1 ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Yes</option>
</select>**
```

What can be different than on my local NAS?

EDIT:

I tried this (all results are 1):

```
$this->active = $row['active'] == true ? '1' : '0';
```

and this (all results are 0):

```
$this->active = $row['active'] == 1? '1' : '0';
```

EDIT 2:

just tried a simple query (no mysqli) and I get an empty result for all my bit-fields

Answer (score 0):

the following condition will only work if you have selected the value 1 from the active dropdown

```
if(isset($_POST['active']))
```

you need to replace it with the following

```
if(!$_POST['active']) {
    $_POST['active'] = 0;
}else{
   $_POST['active'] = 1;
}
```

OR Solution 2

update the following values in drop down

```
<select type="text" name="active" id="active" class="txt">
    <option value="1" <?php echo $member->active == 1 ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>No</option>
    <option value="2" <?php echo $member->active == 2 ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Yes</option>
</select>**
```

it will not bypass your if condition.

Comment: so store as int and not as bit. Thx, but why can't I retrieve the stored values? (see edit)